Why does os.unlink() raise permission error on windows and not on macOS?
I'm a python beginner, and I was doing some stuff with cv2 and os.unlink() when I got a Permission Error.
This was like the overall structure of the code.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tempfile
import os
import time






# Function to create and delete a temporary image file
def calculate_tumor_location(frame):
    #We are accessing the global variables tumorX, tumorY in this function
    global tumorX, tumorY

    if ai_mode_enabled:
        rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # Save the frame temporarily
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.jpg') as tmp_file:
            cv2.imwrite(tmp_file.name, cv2.cvtColor(rgb_frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            
           
            prediction = client.infer(tmp_file.name)
            sum_x = 0
            sum_y = 0
            count = 0
            
            
            for detection in prediction:
                points = detection['points']
                for point in points:
                    sum_x += int(point['x'])
                    sum_y += int(point['y'])
                    count += 1
                
                
                #------Assigning colors---------
                
                contour = np.array([[int(point['x']), int(point['y'])] for point in points], dtype=np.int32).reshape((-1, 1, 2))
                cv2.polylines(frame, [contour], isClosed=True, color=brgcolor, thickness=2)
                cv2.putText(frame, detection['class'],(int(point['x']),int(point['y'])),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,brgcolor,3)
            
            if count > 0:
                # Calculate midpoint
                midpoint_x = sum_x / count
                midpoint_y = sum_y / count
                
                # Update global variables                    
                tumorX = midpoint_x
                tumorY = midpoint_y


        os.unlink(tmp_file.name)        
    
    return frame


I figured that it was because I had the os.unlink() line inside the with clause, but on my friend's mac the code worked fine even though the line was indented. Am I missing something? I know how to get the code to work now but is it just how Windows deals with file handling or is it something much simpler that I just missed.

Besides doing something that documentation warns you about, what's exactly the point of writing the file to the disk and then immediately reading it back (especially using a lossy compression format)?

I don't use Windows but I suspect the problem is that you're calling unlink on an open file. Move the unlnk outside the context managed code block. On a Unix type system the unlink won't take any effect until the file is closed. Having said that, what are you really trying to do?

I was trying to project a live instance segmentation output from roboflow from a camera port, and I was projecting the outline of the object that I was detecting and then deleting it continuously.

Per documentation (emphasis mine):

os.unlink(path, *, dir_fd=None)
...This function is semantically identical to remove()
os.remove(path, *, dir_fd=None)
...
On Windows, attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be raised; on Unix, the directory entry is removed but the storage allocated to the file is not made available until the original file is no longer in use.

Just use delete=True (the default) and it will work on both OSes:
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.tmp') as tmp_file:
    print(tmp_file.name)
# file gone after with

